# Overriding click to pause with click to select, when selecting a video

Tags: selection, video

I'm designing an interface where a user needs to select a video from a library of videos in a modal window. Once the selection is made, the modal closes and they end up back on the page they started.

I was planning on having the video start playing on mouse-over and have the sound mutued. The user would also see a "Click to select" instruction appear when they hovered over the video.

I'm wondering if it's acceptable to override clicking to pause the video with clicking to select? (My concern is that someone may expect to pause the video on click, instead of select it)

The user would be able to pause the video by using the play menu bar that also appears on hover.

I'm making the assumption that stoping the video is a secondary action since the  the user can just move from one video to the other by scrolling through the modal.

Answer (score 1):

Does the user need that much control over the thumbnail? 
If not, the autoplay should suffice to clear what the video is about and help them select it (I believe that's the goal in the autoplay, right?).

As for clicking to select, The purpose of the modal and the message on it are about selecting the video, right? So a border around the video on mouseover (or some other form of affordance) should make ir clear that click will select it.

Comment: Yep, I was planning to use a border or some indicator that he video is selected. My concern is that someone may click the video to pause it and be surprised that they selected it.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about that, I think play/pause control patterns on thumbnails usually clearly indicate a play/pause button on overlay.

Comment: +1 - I agree there is no need for that much need for control in the thumbnails, hovering is normally a preview, clicking is normally selecting.